# Describe all non-diagonalizable $4 \times 4$ matrices over $\mathbb{Q}$ such that $A^5 + A^2 = 0$ up to similarity. Justify your answer.

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to solve the following problem

Describe all non-diagonalizable $4 \times 4$ matrices over $\mathbb{Q}$ such that $A^5 + A^2 = 0$ up to similarity. Justify your answer.

I think we're going to want to use the identity $A^5 + A^2 = A^2(A+1)(A^2 - A+1)$. However, I'm not sure how this will help us.

Comment: It tells you that for each Jordan block of $A$ the minimal polynomial is one of those three factors.